# Xamarin ios info.plis on Windows 10 Visual Studio overwrites changes when archiving for distribution

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm running into an issue with App Store connect that many people have when tring to upload an iOs app for distribution. "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist"

When I make the required changes in my Visual Studio solution and save the info.plist file, then go to archive the ios app for release, the info.plist doesn't match what I have.

After archiving successfully I click the "Open Folder" button, and click the Info file in that folder to see what gets generated. `\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Archives\2021-12-17\App.iOS 12-17-21 11.54 PM.xcarchive`

Ways I've tried to edit the Info.plist file

1. Externally in VS Code
2. With Generic PList Editor in solution
3. View Code in Solution

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

*Update*
I archived from VS on mac as a solution

*Update 2*
I believe I had a typo in the key

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what fixed the problem.

Steps I took:
I ended up loading the solution in VS for mac and Archiving from there
Add items to info.plist for NSCalendarsUsageDescription AND Privacy - Calendars Usage Description
Uploads succesfully
Then try and Archive from windows 10 VS 2019 again
Upload successfully